# Maven Multi Module Project with Spring Boot Module

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, multi-module

I've following Maven Projects Structure:

```
Project 1:
--pom.xml
Project 2:
--pom.xml
Project 3:
--pom.xml
```

i.e. Project1, Project2 and Project3 are peer to each other at directory structure and each of them is Spring Boot Application (JAR).
I want to treat Project2 and Project3 as children of Project1 without changing the directory structure. I need to transitively execute all the maven commands on children project when I execute the same on Parent project. Also and most importantly, I should be able to package all of them in single JAR file.
I searched on Google about it and came across Maven Assembly Plugin and Maven Shade Plugin but those do not seem to help me out.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can make individual jars for project1, project2 and project3. Add project2 and project3 as a dependency to project1. Add project1 as parent to project2 and project3. The corresponding pom files might look like this.

Project 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>project1</artifactId>
    <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <modules>
        <module>project3</module>
        <module>project2</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

Project2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>project1</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>project2</artifactId>
    <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

</project>
```

Project 3:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>project1</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>project2</artifactId>
    <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

</project>
```

I am not sure why you would want everything to be packaged under a single jar. If you follow the above config, everything will be packaged into project1. This essentially would be same as if everything is packaged under a single jar.